# Is survey response number big enough

Tags: sample-size

This is a fictional example to demonstrate my question I'm trying to figure out at work. I sent out surveys to all organizations of a specific type in the US asking them what is the average time it takes their employees to apply sunscreen and average number of applications a day. This means I surveyed the whole population = 400 organizations. I have received 100 complete responses that I can use. Example, organization X said on average their employees take 10 minutes to apply sunscreen with an average number of applications being 3 times a day. I want to find the industry average. So I'm taking the average of all organizations that responded answers to their sunscreen time which is 7.8 minutes. And the average of all respondents application numbers is 4.2 times a day. Basically in this industry, the average sunscreen application time is 7.8 minutes and # of times it's applied is 4.2.

How do I know if having 100 complete responses for this type of survey is sufficient? Is there a specific formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that whether people responded was random (hopefully they didn't self-select to push an agenda!), then the answer will depend what you mean by sufficient. (You might want to edit your question to make that more clear)

Possibly you want to do hypothesis testing with these means, then you will might want to do power analysis.

Possibly, and I'm just guessing this from your question; you want to know is my sample large enough to give precise and stable estimates of the population mean. Then the formula would be this:

$n \geq N (1+ N(\frac{B}{Z_\frac{\alpha}{2} \sigma})^2)^{-1} $

Where N is your population size=400

B is the confidence interval of your estimated mean that you would find acceptable. The whole thing hinges on B; it is whatever you would accept, make it smaller (more precise estimate with smaller variance) and you'll need a bigger sample.

$Z_\frac{\alpha}{2}$ is the probability that you could get a number outside of that B. sub in 1.96 if you want 95% (a conventional amount)

$ \sigma$ is your population standard deviation, but you can sub in your sample standard deviation as an estimate of it.